# LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.gister while current state is STARTED

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I am currently writing code in Android Studio to build a system that processes payments when a QR code is scanned. I have encountered an error saying "LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED" while the current state is STARTED. It seems to be related to the lifecycle, and I would like to request assistance on how to modify the code to resolve the issue.

I have tried modifying various code related to the lifecycle, but I continue to encounter errors related to the lifecycle component.

package com.project.tosspayment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var paymentWidget: PaymentWidget
lateinit var customDialogBinding: CustomDialogBinding

private val REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)


    onResume()

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
    } else {
        openScanner()
    }

}

private fun openScanner(){
    val QrScan = IntentIntegrator(this)
    QrScan.setCameraId(0) //후방카메라 사용
    QrScan.setBeepEnabled(false) //스캔할때 소리 끄기
    QrScan.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE","QR코드를 스캔해주세요")
    QrScan.setOrientationLocked(false)
    QrScan.initiateScan()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray ) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when(requestCode){
        REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION -> {
            if(grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                openScanner()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"카메라를 허용해 주세요",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            return
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    Log.w("zio","TossScanner")


    val result:IntentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data)
    val scannerData = result.contents

    Log.w("zio","scannerData: $scannerData")

    if(scannerData == null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"QR코드를 다시 스캔해주세요!!!!!!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return
    }

   if(requestCode == IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
       val pattern =
           Pattern.compile("\\{\"orderId\":\"([A-Za-z0-9]+)\",\"price\":(\\d+),\"orderItem\":\"([^,]+)\",\"customerKey\":\"([A-Za-z0-9]+)\"\\}")

       val matcher = pattern.matcher(scannerData ?: "")
       Log.w("zio","pattern : $pattern")
       Log.w("zio","matcher: $matcher")

       if (matcher.find()) {
           val orderId = matcher.group(1)
           val price = matcher.group(2).toDouble()
           val orderItem = matcher.group(3)
           val customerKey = matcher.group(4)

            //위젯 생성하기 위해 생성
            val methodWidget = binding.paymentWidget
            val agreement = binding.agreementWidget

            //위젯에 값전달
            paymentWidget = PaymentWidget(
                this@MainActivity,
                getString(R.string.payment_ClientKey),
                customerKey //PaymentWidget.ANONYMOUS
            )

           Log.w("zio","에러: $paymentWidget")

            //가격과 주문번호
            paymentWidget.renderPaymentMethods(
                method = methodWidget,
                amount = price
            )

            //이용약관 위젯
            paymentWidget.renderAgreement(agreement)
            //결제위젯 view
            PaymentMethod(this, null)
            //이용약관 view
            Agreement(this, null)

            binding.payAccess.setOnClickListener {
                customDialogBinding = CustomDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

                paymentWidget.requestPayment(
                    paymentInfo = PaymentMethod.PaymentInfo(
                        orderId = orderId,
                        orderName = orderItem
                    ),

                    paymentCallback = object : PaymentCallback,
                        com.tosspayments.paymentsdk.model.PaymentCallback {

                        override fun onPaymentSuccess(success: TossPaymentResult.Success) {

                            val client = OkHttpClient()

                            val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json")
                            val qrBody = RequestBody.create(
                                mediaType,
                                "{\"paymentKey\":\"${success.paymentKey}\",\"amount\":$price,\"orderId\":\"$orderId\",\"customerName\":\"$customerKey\",\"orderName\":\"$orderItem\"}"
                            )
                            Log.w("zio", "paymentKey: ${success.paymentKey}")

                            val request = Request.Builder()
                                .url("https://api.tosspayments.com/v1/payments/confirm")
                                .header(
                                    "Authorization",
                                    "Basic dGVzdF9za19aT1J6ZE1hcU4zd015a1p5bDdOcjVBa1lYUUd3Og=="
                                )
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .post(qrBody)
                                .build()

                            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : okhttp3.Callback {

                                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                                    runOnUiThread {
                                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                                            Log.w("zio", "결제인증 성공")
                                            dialog(
                                                "결제가 되었습니다.",
                                                "결제요청 결과",
                                                customDialogBinding.dialogButton.setOnClickListener {
                                                    val successIntent =
                                                        Intent(this@MainActivity,ReceiptActivity::class.java)
                                                    startActivity(successIntent)
                                                })
                                        } else {
                                            Log.w(
                                                "zio",
                                                "결제인증 재 시작: $response, orderid: $orderId"
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                override fun onFailure(call: okhttp3.Call, e: IOException) {
                                    runOnUiThread {
                                        Log.w("zio", "결제인증 실패")
                                        dialog(
                                            "결제가 실패돼었습니다..",
                                            "결제요청 결과",
                                            customDialogBinding.dialogButton.setOnClickListener {
                                                val failIntent =
                                                    Intent(this@MainActivity,PaymentActivity::class.java)
                                                startActivity(failIntent)
                                            })
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }

                        override fun onPaymentFailed(fail: TossPaymentResult.Fail) {
                            Log.d("zio", "결제 실패 !")
                            dialog(
                                "결제가 실패돼었습니다..",
                                "결제요청 결과",
                                customDialogBinding.dialogButton.setOnClickListener {
                                    val failIntent =
                                        Intent(this@MainActivity, PaymentActivity::class.java)
                                    startActivity(failIntent)
                                })
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        } else {
            Log.w("zio","No match found")
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"QR코드를 다시 스캔해주세요",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       return
    }
}

fun dialog(message:String, title:String, OnClickListener: Unit) {

    val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(customDialogBinding.customDialog)
        .create()

    customDialogBinding.dialogTitle.text = title
    customDialogBinding.dialogMessage.text = message
    customDialogBinding.dialogButton.text = "확인"
    customDialogBinding.dialogMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    customDialogBinding.dialogButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    alertDialog.show()
}
```

}